# Where is "Reader Mode" icon in address bar of Safari 15 for macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, safari

In Safari 14, if ["Reader Mode"](https://www.macworld.com/article/230270/how-to-use-reader-mode-in-safari-11.html) was available, a "page" icon appeared next to the address bar. Clicking that icon activated Reader Mode for that page.

In Safari 15, that icon is gone.

For example, see this article in *Wired*, [*Review: Apple iPad Mini (2021)*](https://www.wired.com/review/apple-ipad-mini-2021/#intcid=_wired-bottom-recirc_46afbff0-f89b-42f2-b9e4-dc4f8bd55811_entity-topic-similarity-v2-reranked-by-vidi).

[image: screenshot of a Wired.com article with Safari 15 address bar lacking the Reader Mode icon]

I find I can still activate Reader mode by choosing the menu item `View` > `Show Reader`. Ironically, after doing so that page icon appears in the old location, available to turn *off* Reader Mode. But how can I similarly turn *on* reader mode with a quick click of an icon?

Comment: May be CMD+SHIFT+R

Comment: The icon is in the same spot as before (left edge of the address bar). It doesn't show up for me on the article you have open either, but works fine on others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reader Mode does not properly recognize the article you've linked to. It would not have appeared in previous versions either.

Reader Mode icon appears within the address bar on the left side

[image: A screenshot showing a Reader Mode icon within the address bar, left of the URL itself]